# How do I unit test Active Directory object creation?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, active-directory

I am creating a user like this:

```
using (var AD = new DirectoryEntry(myCOntainer, myUsername, myPassword))
            {
                var user = AD.Children.Add("CN=testuser", "user");
                user.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = "test01";
                user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = Constant.NormalAccount + Constant.AccountDisable;
                user.CommitChanges();
                AD.CommitChanges();
            }
```

What is the best way for creating unit test for this method? I think invoking this method on the real AD where my users at would be a bad choice. Also I have to make sure I delete the test created user.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You can make use of a dedicated non-prod environment if you have one available. If you dont have a non-prod environment, you can slice a portion of existing active directory and make use of it - provided the objective is only for testing AD object creation.

By Slicing the production AD, I mean to have the below setup.

1. Create a Dedicated OU in Prod AD for this testing
2. Create a service account and delegated the required access only on this Test OU
3. Bind the Test OU location and the service account on your code and get the testing done

As long as the service account is getting used for testing, we are limiting the access within that TEST OU.

Good luck !

Comment: Because of how AD issues Relative Identifiers (RID, which is part of the object's SID), AD has a maximum number of objects that can be created in the lifetime of the domain (even if old objects are deleted). That is about 1 billion objects. That's a lot, but once you hit that number, you cannot create any new objects on the domain anymore. I don't think it would be a good idea to be creating new objects in prod for unit testing. Here's some reading about it: [Managing RID Issuance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/managing-rid-issuance)